# When I change my local english to bengali this time calendar date picker show english format in android

Tags: android, kotlin, localization, android-datepicker

I have to make multi language application. When I am converting language from English to Benglai, whole view of application is changed. But my date picker can't change. It's shows English format while I select Bengali language, again when I select English language then date picker shows Benglai format. How can I solve this. Here I show my code:

**LocaleCode.kt**

```
fun setLocale() {
    var sm: SessionManager = SessionManager()
    val lang = sm.languageCode

    if (lang != "") {
        lang?.let {
            val locale = Locale(it)
            Locale.setDefault(locale)
            val config = Configuration()
            config.locale = locale
            baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)
            AppController.setLocale(it)
        }
     } else {

        sm.language = "Bangla"
        sm.languageCode = "en"

        val locale = Locale("en")
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = Configuration()
        config.locale = locale
        baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)

        AppController.setLocale("en")

    }

}
```

**Activity.kt**

```
@OnClick(R.id.expire_date)
fun OnExpiryDate() {

    val c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
    val dialog = Dialog(requireActivity())
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_datepicker)

    val cancel = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.datepicker_cancel) as TextView
    val picker = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.datePicker) as DatePicker
    val ok = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.datepicker_ok) as TextView

    cancel.setOnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() }

    picker.minDate = c.timeInMillis

    ok.setOnClickListener {

        c.set(picker.year, picker.month, picker.dayOfMonth)
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
        val dateString = format.format(c.time)

        tvExpiryDate.text = dateString
        isExpiryDateChanged = true

        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    dialog.show()

}
```

acitivty_main.xml

```
<TextView
      android:background="@drawable/a_border"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:hint="@string/yyyymmdd"
      android:id="@+id/tv_expiredate_text"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tv_expiredate"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:paddingStart="8dp"
      android:text="expiredDate"
      android:textAlignment="viewStart"
      android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

Here is output:

[See this picture, when I select Bengali it shows English format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnvkR.jpg)

[See this picture, when I select English it shows Benglai format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go6IE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the locale to English here.

```
@OnClick(R.id.expire_date) 
fun OnExpiryDate() 
{ 
val c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Instead you can save the selected locale locally and pass the selected locale here

Comment: I did it but doesn't work. When i print on log calendar instance that show timezone "asia/dhaka" i set the timezone "UTC" but no change